# Is it possible to install Kerberos for different distros?

Tags: ubuntu, kerberos, alma-linux

I want to install Kerberos on AlmaLinux as server to manage Ubuntu clients. is this possible? I read somewhere that in order to use Kerberos, ["Both devices have the same operating system"](https://linuxhint.com/install-kerberos-linux/).

Do you know a complete Kerberos training?

So both systems must use Ubuntu?

Comment: Whoever said `Both devices have the same operating system` is talking complete rubbish. You can have server on Windows, client on any Linux distro or vice versa. Distro matters not a jot. If you want MacOS involved, then go ahead. Goog grief, even Microsoft Active Directory is based on the Kerberos protocols and has been handling Unix systems since its inception.

Answer (score 0):

Your [original question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1454517/is-it-possible-to-install-kerberos-for-different-distros/1454523#1454523) in Ask Ubuntu is still open. If you move a question to a different site, you should close the first one as [cross-posting isn't acceptable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

The page which you linked as source (which I added to this question) says *".. explanation of how to set up and design Kerberos **in a Cluster**"* and *"Introduce Kerberos KDC client on every one of the nodes or machines **in the cluster**..."*

Unless you're planning to do just that, the page isn't applicable. There are no restrictions regarding the client OS.

You can find Kerberos trainings simply by searching the web. Here's one example from Educative: [Kerberos for Beginners: Intro to Network Authentication Protocol](https://www.educative.io/courses/kerberos-for-beginners-intro-network-authentication-protocol)

[The MIT Kerberos Documentation](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/www/krb5-latest/doc/index.html#)